# Testcafe Selector.exists doesn&#39;t return a boolean

Tags: javascript, html, css, testing, testcafe

I want to do some action in case `Selector('#particularButton-view').exists` is `true` and some other action in case is `false`.

The problem is that it doesn't return a boolean. It returns some object. It's made to be used like this:

```
testController.expect(Selector('#particularButton-view').exists).ok()
```

How can I do to perform some action in each case?

Answer (score 4):

Selector properties are wrapped in Promises, so to obtain a value you can use `await` from ES2017:

```
await Selector('...').exists;
```

If you can't use `await`, you can get the value by using `then` method of the promise, like:

```
Selector('...')
    .exists
    .then(exists => {
        If (exists)
            Foo();
        else
            Bar();
    })
```